# nokogiri.so LoadError maybe problem with libiconv on Solaris

Tags: ruby, solaris, nokogiri, libiconv

I'm trying to get the Ruby gem "Nokogiri" running on a Solaris machine where I don't have root priviledges. What I've done so far:

- I've build my own ruby version (1.9.2p180) in my home directory
- tried to install nokogiri with "gem install nokogiri"

The gem install then throwed this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/bender/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

So I downloaded and build the libiconv in /home/myuser/work/libiconv

```
$ ls /home/myuser/work/libiconv/
bin      build    include  lib      share
```

And passed the locations as arguments for nokogiri:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/home/myuser/work/libiconv --with-iconv-include=/home/myuser/work/libiconv/include --with-iconv-lib=/home/myuser/work/libiconv/lib
```

Now the gem builds and no errors are displayed. The problem is, when I now try to use it, e.g. in irb it somehow fails to load:

```
require 'nokogiri'
LoadError: ld.so.1: ruby: fatal: libiconv.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory - /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
    from /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `require'
    from /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/myuser/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

But when I look for the file which should be missing it is there and also readable/executable:

```
ll /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/
total 66
...
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser   group      370552 Jun  6 22:53 nokogiri.so
...
```

Ok, and that is where I'm stuck.. the file is there but can't be opened? I tried to rebuild the libiconv which had no effect. Nokogiri doesn't throw any error that the build process fails. So I don't know how to solve this and google could't give me answers either. I hope somebody here can give me some hints.

/edit

I googled around some more and found [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/solaris-opensolaris-20/rsync-solaris-ld-so-1-rsync-fatal-libiconv-so-2-open-failed-736845/) where somebody uses ldd to show dependencies. When I do the same for nokogiri it says:

```
ldd /home/myuser/ruby/bin/nokogiri
ldd: /home/myuser/ruby/bin/nokogiri: unsupported or unknown file type
```

I guess this is because its a ruby file but in case it is relevant I want to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU binutils, then try to set

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /home/myuser/work/libiconv/lib"
```

if it's a Solaris linker, then it's something like -X, I don't really remember. Just check the man page of ld for runpath settings. It'll allow the run-time linker to find the .so.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it right. I've searched the solaris ld manpage and found as option "-R", the manpages says: "A colon-separated list of directories  used  to  specify library  search  directories  to  the runtime linker.". It seems to me that this is the option you meant, set LDFLAGS to "-R /home/myuser/work/libiconv/lib" and build libiconv and the nokogiri gem from scratch. Unfortunately the error remains. ( LoadError: ld.so.1: ruby: fatal: libiconv.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory - /home/myuser/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so )

Comment: Well, you're compiling with gcc, probably, so you will probably need to set LDFLAGS='-Wl,-R -Wl,/some/path' . The gcc calls the Solaris ld with the parameters which follow -Wl, . I think that in my time (like 14 years ago), it was like -Xlinker -R -Xlinker /some/path

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to build your own sandbox, why not use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) to do all the heavy lifting? Its purpose in life is to create a user sandbox in `~/.rvm`, build and manage the Ruby versions you want to run and the gemsets associated with your projects.

If you decide to go that path, which I recommend highly, be sure to follow the single-user installation directions on the linked page, to add the appropriate string to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` if you you don't use a *profile file, and follow the recommendations RVM outputs when you run `rvm notes`.

I have it installed on several Centos, Ubuntu and Mac OS boxes where I do development, and think it's great.

Comment: I'm using rvm without problems on my local machine (ubuntu), but on that solaris server it fails to install with:

    Installing RVM to /home/bender/.rvm/awk: syntax error near line 1
    awk: bailing out near line 1
    /home/myuser/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/functions/installer: line 364: cp: No such file or directory

I googled for that problem and found a gist (but unfortunately without solution here) here: https://gist.github.com/921374 and some japanese stuff here: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/murase_syuka/20101002/1286028764 , which I don't understand. :S

Comment: I'd recommend bouncing it off the author. You can get his email address using `rvm -v`.